# ANT : 'ZIP' Task - how to prevent trailing slashes on ZIP entries?

Tags: ant, zip, apache-poi

I am using ANT to both unzip and then re-zip a "Open Packaging Convention" file.

It happens to be an EXCEL (*.xlsx) file: and the process works; but it seems that the ANT 'zip' task is creating the ZIP slightly differently that how it was created by EXCEL itself.

The ZIP entries created appear to have trailing slash characters.
I discovered this when opening the resultant ZIP with Apache POI (which has some unit-tests to detect and complain about this situation) with DEBUG logging on.

Here's an example of the WARNING log messages from Apache POI when re-opening up the re-zipped file:

```
2015-10-29 14:06:11 WARN  ZipPackage:135 - Entry xl/worksheets/_rels/ is not valid, so this part won't be add to the package.
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: A part name shall not have a forward slash as the last character [M1.5]: /xl/worksheets/_rels/
```

Is there a way of avoiding this (annoying, but not critical) issue when using Ant ?

I'm running this on a Windows platform.

Here's my (simplified) 'build.xml' file.

```
<project name="repackage" default="repackage" basedir=".">

<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="build" location="build"/>
<property name="temp" location="temp"/>
<property name="extract" location="${temp}\extract"/>
<property name="inputfile" value="original.xlsx"/> 

<target name="cleantemp">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                <fileset dir="${temp}" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${extract}"/>
</target>

<target name="extract" depends="cleantemp">
        <unzip src="${src}/${inputfile}" dest="${extract}"/>
</target>

<target name="reassemble" depends="extract">
        <zip destfile="${build}/repair.xlsx" basedir="${extract}"/>
</target>

<target name="repackage" depends="reassemble">
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: Does it work on Linux? (I'm wondering if it's a windows filesystem limitation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the parser you use didn't like directory entries (which end in a `/`). Use `filesonly="true"` in your `<zip>` task.